# Convert LIST of JSONs to a list of strings using postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql, list

I have this of `JSON` object :

```
[{"name":"steven","dob":"1979-02-10"},{"name":"Chris","dob":"1981-01-05"},]
```

I want to convert the object above to a `LIST` of the names from the `JSON` objects like :

```
["steven", "Chris"]
```

Is there's a postgresql function to do that?

I checked the documentation [HERE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html) and could not find the right function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT json_agg(value->>'name') FROM json_array_elements('[{"name":"steven","dob":"1979-02-10"},{"name":"Chris","dob":"1981-01-05"}]');
```

Comment: since the version of Postgres is 9.4 or above.

Comment: it works! thank you! I have the list of JSON in one column in a table called consumers_info.colum_1  had this kind of values : [{"name":"steven","dob":"1979-02-10"},{"name":"Chris","dob":"1981-01-05"},]
how to use to use the above function is much format `SELECT colum_1 FROM consumers_info`?

Comment: I am not sure I understand exactly what you ask for, but maybe you want something like this: `SELECT (SELECT json_agg(value->>'name') FROM json_array_elements(colum_1)) FROM consumers_info`